# fastest way to drop sparse groups?

Tags: pandas

I've got some pandas code to drop groups that aren't part of full sets.  An example of what the code below is doing is:

1. creating groups
2. getting the size of the largest group.  e.g., 72
3. dropping all rows that aren't in the largest groups.  i.e., if i regroup, every group will be of size 72

the first way of doing step 3 makes the most sense to me, but is slow

the second way seems a bit convoluted but is much faster.  may be convoluted because `groups` index is a subset of `medians` index.  (both indices are multi-indices)

is there a fast, intuitive way to do this?

```py
    # filter out groups that are uncommon
    groups = medians.groupby(group_columns)
    max_group_size = groups.size().max()

    # # takes 84s
    # %time medians = groups.filter(lambda group: len(group) == max_group_size)

    # takes 34s
    groups_size = groups.size().to_frame('size')
    groups_to_drop = groups_size[groups_size.size != max_group_size].index
    %time medians = medians.drop(groups_to_drop)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new `Series` like original DataFrame, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
size = medians.groupby(group_columns)['any column'].transform('size')
output = medians[size == size.max()]
```

Comment: t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶m̶a̶k̶e̶s̶ ̶s̶e̶n̶s̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶7̶5̶x̶ ̶f̶a̶s̶t̶e̶r̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶g̶i̶v̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶r̶o̶w̶s̶.̶.̶.̶?̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶s̶ ̶1̶2̶9̶9̶0̶4̶6̶ ̶r̶o̶w̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶m̶i̶n̶e̶ ̶h̶a̶s̶ ̶1̶2̶7̶7̶8̶2̶ ̶r̶o̶w̶s̶   oh ha.  i see your edit.  i should've caught that the first time

Comment: @Jayen - hmmm, I think I change answer later from `!=` to `==`

Comment: this ended up 12x faster than your solution: `medians = medians[groups['median'].transform('size') == max_num_periods]` (since i already had the groups from a previous operation)